# Trying to add another row on top of my Col headers for the name of Wkdys and insert cols in b/w them with 8 hrs b/w that all the cols

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime

This is the snippet of the Data set I have, I want to first add a row on top of my the Column headers with the name of Weekdays-(Sunday though Saturday) with respect to the date below them and also insert columns between each of the dates and have 8 hours added to the respective times, I have tried a lot of ways but am unsuccessful.

I tried

```
df.columns = df.columns.dt.day_name()
```

Didn't work to change the dates to Weekdays

Also for adding the new columns i tried

```
 df['new_time'] = df['07-26-2020'].apply(lambda x:(dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime(1,1,1), x,) + dt.timedelta(hours=7,minutes=30)).time())
```

First of all this did not work,and also i want more dynamic since the dates will change and i do not want to change the code every time.

Can you please help?

Thank you

[Please take a look at this snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwQze.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to change your columns to a multi-level index

1. Sample data is not provided so I've simulated column headings
2. I've built columns array in two ways.  1st will result in time coming out in date.  2nd results in column heading being a string

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Person","Productivity"]+[d for d in pd.date_range(start='7/26/2019', end='8/1/2019')])
cols = [["" if isinstance(d, str) else d.day_name() for d in df.columns],
        df.columns]
cols = [["" if isinstance(d, str) else d.day_name() for d in df.columns],
        [d if isinstance(d, str) else d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") for d in df.columns]]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*cols)))
df
```

**output**

```
                        Friday      Saturday    Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday
Person  Productivity    07-26-2019  07-27-2019  07-28-2019  07-29-2019  07-30-2019  07-31-2019  08-01-2019
```

**include breakdown with 8hr columns**

For flexibility I've included a filter so that only *00:00* and *08:00* will be included `d.hour < 12`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Person","Productivity"]+
                  [d for d in pd.date_range(start='7/26/2019', 
                                            end='8/1/2019 23:59', freq="8H") 
                   if d.hour<12])
cols = [
        ["" if isinstance(d, str) else d.day_name() for d in df.columns],
        ["" if isinstance(d, str) else d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") for d in df.columns],
        [d if isinstance(d, str) else d.strftime("%H:%M") for d in df.columns ]
        ]
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*cols)))
df

                        Friday         Saturday           Sunday           Monday          Tuesday        Wednesday         Thursday      
                        07-26-2019       07-27-2019       07-28-2019       07-29-2019       07-30-2019       07-31-2019       08-01-2019      
Person Productivity     00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00      00:00 08:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much,This is great exactly what i was looking for the Column headers.

Comment: Can you please help me with the second part of my problem where i want to as alternate column between each of the present ones and then for their values add 8 hours to them.Really been struggling to get that part.

Comment: Your image shows it as rows of data not columns....  do you mean you want additional column headers that mean you see columns on 00:00, 08:00, 16:00 under each day?  Best if you mock up exactly what column headings you are looking for in text format.